# Always show next Calendar appointment on lock-screen

Tags: lock-screens, calendar, outlook

One feature I dreadfully miss from Windows Phone was that my next calendar event was always displayed on my lockscreen:

[image]

I now use the Outlook application on Android to manage my daily life. Is there a way to enable a similar feature on Android?

Comment: Afraid not without root. That feature *was* available until someone decided to ban it with the release of Android 5 (Lollipop).

Comment: I missed this one badly.

Comment: This is a far cry from what Windows Phone OS offers out-of-the box, but of everything I tried recently, the least worst option seems to be Calendar Notify Agenda Status (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cliffcawley.calendarnotify&hl=en). I have been trying it for a few hours and it seems like an okay alternative (I'm not using the widget part of it, just the lock screen notifications).